# Black screen during installation

Tags: boot, nvidia, system-installation, live-usb

Im trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my HTPC. I have burned the ISO image to a USB flash drive and when I try to boot from it, first of all  apears the Ubuntu logo and in few seconds, screen goes black and doesnt do anything. I have tried to boot from a DVD with the same version and happens the same. Hardware: i7-2700K, nVidia GTX 560.
Thank you and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

I have browsed the internet and I have found that by adding the nomodeset parameter at the boot, system boots up correctly